# How to calculate speed from acceleration using systemC AMS and TDF modeling formalism

Tags: systemc

I have a constant acceleration and I need to calculate the instantaneous speed and the travelled distance.
So we know that the speed is the integral of acceleration and the travelled distance is the integral of the speed.
Using systemC AMS with the TDF modeling formalism, there isn't the integral operator, but there is the Laplace transform operator instead.

The schema for the speed and distance calculation that I would realize is the follow:
[image]

NB:

```
// Declaration of private variables of SCA_TDF_MODULE
sca_tdf::sca_ltf_nd lft;
sca_util::sca_vector<double> num, den;

// initialisation of variables 
num(0) = 1.0;
den(0) = 1.0;
```

So I thought that I could calculate the speed using the `sca_tdf::sca_ltf_nd` in this way:

```
if (throttle_is_active) {
        speed.write(lft(num, den, 2.78)); // speed is an output port
        // distance .... 
}
```

But I'm not sure that is right, and I don't know how to save this value to calculate the travelled distance using the ltf again.
The definition of tdf module can be found [here](http://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/systemc/SystemC_AMS_2_0_LRM.pdf).
Anyone can help me please?

see also SystemC AMS Users Guide provided with the proof-of-concept library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients in SystemC-AMS are defined as follows:

```
H(s) = (num(0) + num(1)*s + num(2)*s**2 ...) / (den(0) + den(1)*s + den(2)*s**2 ...)
```

-> the coefficients for an integrator are:

```
num(0)=1.0;
den(0)=0.0;
den(1)=1.0;
```